# SharePoint Designer 2013 Edit Site Pages

Tags: sharepoint

Here i have a issue with SharePoint Designer 2013, an Modern site page was build on SharePoint Online. But i need to customize the modern page and adding url to quick links.

Though modern page doesn't support CEWP or SEWP it's hard to custom the page. But what i am looking is to edit the site pages from SPD 2013 and if i edit the planner.aspx will changes save, unfortune i have Url to navigate the user from the one page to other url(https://...Planner.aspx).

What i want is when user clicks on above link, it should open in new tab and i have to align the page with Css branding. i am adding something like this to open in new tab using SPD href="/abc/xyz/3/SitePages/Planner.aspx?web=1 target="_blank" but no luck at the end.

Looking for an solution, Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, using SharePoint Designer is not supported for modying the SharePoint modern experience.

You should be using the SharePoint Framework to modify your pages, you can see the full list of supported modifications here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations

However, if you are used to using CEWP and SEWP, you can deploy an app which replicates the functionality in the modern pages

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor

Atlthough this is probably not supported either, it should allow you to make the changes you want.